# C# GDI Transforms and mouse click

Tags: c#, gdi

I have a number of object drawn in world co-ordinates with arbitrary transforms - rotation & scaling. I want to pick one of the objects via a mouse click, I have the rectangles of the objects but need to transform the mouse click co-ordinates in order to select the picked object. At the simplest I draw an object with transform (middle of bitmap) and rotate (45).  How do I map the mouse click in the graphics area back to the world space of the objects?
Thanks
Richard

Comment: The Matrix class is your friend.  You can get it from the Graphics object after calling the RotateTransform and ScaleTransform methods from the Transform property.  Use its Invert() method and store it in a variable.  Now you can trivially map the mouse coordinates with TransformPoints().

Comment: Genius, thank you. You have no idea how many hours I spent on trying to drag trigonometry back into my brain.